# Google Location services Android

Tags: android, google-location-services

I am using google fused location API and I was able to successfully implement it but it appears like this I have the logs:

```
Location[fused 31******,30****** acc=27 et=+16h8m55s272ms]
```

I can't figure the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i managed to get it by casting it to double

```
Double.toString(location.getLatitude())
```

Answer (score 0):

This is Location **Service** which runs in **background** and **Tested**

```
public class LocationTrackingService extends Service implements
    GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, LocationListener {

protected static final String TAG = "location-updates-sample";
private Context context;
public static final long UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS = 1000;
public static final long FASTEST_UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS = UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS / 2;
Location mLastLocation;
private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
private LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
protected Location mCurrentLocation;
protected Boolean mRequestingLocationUpdates;
private String locationIntent;

@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
    Log.i(TAG, "Connected to GoogleApiClient");

    if (mCurrentLocation == null) {
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            return;
        }
        mCurrentLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);
    }
    startLocationUpdates();
}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
    mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

    if (locationIntent.equals(AppConstants.LOCATION_INTENT)) {
        EventBus.getDefault().post(new CurrentLocation(location));
        Log.e(TAG, "LOCATION CHANGED :  " + "  " + DateFormat.getTimeInstance().format(new Date()) + "  " + location.getLatitude() + "  " + location.getLongitude());
        //stopLocationUpdates();
        //mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
    } else if (location.equals(AppConstants.LOCATION_TRACK_INTENT)) {
        startLocationUpdates();
        Log.e(TAG, "TRACK LOCATION :  " + "  " + DateFormat.getTimeInstance().format(new Date()) + "  " + location.getLatitude() + "  " + location.getLongitude());
    }
}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
    buildGoogleApiClient();
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}

@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    if (intent != null) {
        context = this;
        locationIntent = intent.getStringExtra(AppConstants.LOCATION_INTENT);
        Toast.makeText(this, "Service Started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    return START_STICKY;
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    // handler.removeCallbacks(sendUpdatesToUI);
    super.onDestroy();
    Log.e("STOP_SERVICE", "STOP_SERVICE");
    stopLocationUpdates();
    mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
}


@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    buildGoogleApiClient();
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    Toast.makeText(this, "service", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

/**
 * Builds a GoogleApiClient. Uses the {@code #addApi} method to request the
 * LocationServices API.
 */
protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
    Log.e(TAG, "Building GoogleApiClient");
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .build();
    createLocationRequest();
}

/**
 * Sets up the location request. Android has two location request settings:
 * {@code ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION} and {@code ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}. These settings control
 * the accuracy of the current location. This sample uses ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, as defined in
 * the AndroidManifest.xml.
 * <p>
 * When the ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION setting is specified, combined with a fast update
 * interval (5 seconds), the Fused Location Provider API returns location updates that are
 * accurate to within a few feet.
 * <p>
 * These settings are appropriate for mapping applications that show real-time location
 * updates.
 */
protected void createLocationRequest() {

    mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
    mLocationRequest.setInterval(UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS);
    mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS);
    mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // TODO: Consider calling
        //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
        // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
        //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
        //                                          int[] grantResults)
        // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
        // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
        return;
    }
    mLastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);
}

/**
 * Requests location updates from the FusedLocationApi.
 */
protected void startLocationUpdates() {

    mRequestingLocationUpdates = true;
        return;
    }
    LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(
            mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
}

/**
 * Removes location updates from the FusedLocationApi.
 */
protected void stopLocationUpdates() {
    // It is a good practice to remove location requests when the activity is in a paused or
    // stopped state. Doing so helps battery performance and is especially
    // recommended in applications that request frequent location updates.

    // The final argument to {@code requestLocationUpdates()} is a LocationListener
    // (http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/LocationListener.html).
    LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, this);
}}
```